# Rectangular form of $z$ without cosine and sine

Tags: complex-numbers

I am programming a numerical application and I managed to get rid of all the sine and cosine usages except for the calculation of the Cartesian form of an array of complex numbers from their polar form.

given a complex number $z_p = \rho ^\theta$, I need to get the Cartesian form $z_c = a + i \cdot b$.

Usually I do:

$$
z_c = \rho \cdot (cos(\theta) + i \cdot sin(\theta))
$$

Which is what I want to avoid because it uses sine and cosine. I also know this other way:

$$
z_c = \rho \cdot e^{- i\theta}
$$
But it boils down to using sine and cosine as in the previous formula (see [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula))

**is there any other way?**

Comment: Any reason why you're doing this? Sine and cosine are pretty well-suited for this kind of thing ...

Comment: How big is $\theta$? You could consider using the Taylor expansion of $\sin$ and $\cos$. If $\theta$ is small, this wouldn't add a lot of computation.

Comment: If you store the complex numbers as the absolute value and the phase, there is no other way around as to use `sin` and/or `cos`. Do you really need both forms for your calculations?

Comment: I don't know where the "Go back to precalculus 101!" comes from but ok. The calculation is called power flow and unfortunately both rectangular and polar forms are needed. I try to avoid sine and cosine as much as possible because numerical method (newton raphson is very sensitive to the accumulated error)

Comment: Why don't you try using a more robust numerical algorithm like binary search? It's a bit slower, true, but on modern computers this is often not even measurable. Plus, you get guaranteed convergence (assuming your initial interval brackets a root), which is impossible with any slope-based methods.

Comment: The power flow problem does not converge with binary search, hence the need for Newton-Raphson and Levenberg-Marquardt type of algorithms

Comment: You obviously have not implemented binary search correctly. While Adrian Keister obviously lacks experience with real-world functions (binary searches are SLOW when function calculation is expensive), they *always* converge when done correctly on a continuous function. On the other hand, Newton-Raphson can easily fail to converge.

Comment: There is no other way - your "other way" is misquoted: $z_c = \rho \cdot e^{i\theta}$,not $e^{-\theta}$ as you've stated. And that formula only holds because $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\cdot\sin \theta$. Which is the problem. If you calculate $z_c$ by any method, then divide the real and imaginary coordinates by $\rho$, you have the value of $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$. I.e., you used a method for calculating cosine and sine.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, but maybe there was something else that I was not aware. (BTW I corrected the formula, indeed it was a typo)